# append new rows to gridview in yii2

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

I need to append some new rows to the top of a table that is created by yii2's gridView.
The gridview's data is provided by an activeDataProvider.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="dataDiv">              
<?php
  echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $model['dataProvider'],
    'columns' => [
      'id',
      'customer_name',
      'customer_lastname',
      'customer_mobile',
      'created_at:date'
    ]
  ]);
?>
</div>
```

I can get the new rows by ajax call to a controller method but I do not know how I can append them to the table back via ajax (jquery).

Any idea would be highly appreciated!

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429111/yii2-add-remove-rows-in-gridview) - here's some JS code that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes late, but for anyone else who wants a solution in future:

First of all, give your GridView an id so that we can work with it in html:

```
GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'some-list',
    ...
]);
```

Let's assume you get the new row directly from the controller as a response, then you want to use jQuery to append the list at the top:

```
$.post('your-saving-url', {someData:'you-want-to-save'}, function(response) {
     // append the new row to the top of our table
     $('#some-list').find('tbody').prepend(response);
});
```

It makes sense to do a pjax refresh after a few seconds to make sure the table structure is still right & to fix the pagination.